# Contributions to the Wiki: Distribution tags

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I've started filling in distro information for the [[arch-linux] tag wiki](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/arch-linux/info)

It would be nice to have a wiki entry for each distribution, and I'm keen to do some work.

But what details should we specify? My suggestion:

- logo
- website
- forums / wiki
- a section devoted to technical details
- a link to wikipedia page on distro

Any other suggestions?

(as a sidenote, it would be cool if you guys fill out the other wiki tags.)

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that you need 1500 reputation and to be either in the top 20 answerers for a given tag or to have at least 100 score in that tag before you can edit the tag wiki, which will unfortunately exclude most users

Comment: for now yes, but everybody has a growing reputation. :D my idea is that this question serves as a guideline reference for editing the distro-tag wiki's. Which is why I want input on 'what details should we include'

Answer (score 4):

Compared with you've done, I don't think there needs to be that much vertical space devoted to the large logo, a large quote about philosophy (I'd prefer a short paragraph), and a large quote about history (again, a short paragraph seems right, beyond this there's Wikipedia). Instead I'd like to see more technical information or pointers for the non-expert, such as:

- Direct access to documentation for people who write portable programs/scripts/documents, for instance:

  - List of software (packages, versions, …) (and popular third-party repositories if applicable)
  - Man pages
- Common tasks with a one-line answer, for instance:

  - I want to install a program on a machine where I have root access, what command do I use? (`pacman -S`, `apt-get install`, …)
  - The main admin is on holiday and there's an Apache hole, how do I make sure the security updates are applied? (`pacman -Syu`, `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`, …)

I've written a first draft of [debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian) and [ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu). Maybe after things settle down we can try to reach a consensus on a template.

Comment: nice.... I have not been quite busy building my career lately... So I have not been too busy on this front. But I like your suggestions. As for the techinal details, won't those be represented by the list of question tagged with the distro. [see](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch-linux)

Comment: @Stefan: I was thinking of a few common tasks, definitely limited to things that can be expressed in a one-line sentence.

Comment: mm. yes I see. And I like what you've done with debain and ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think most of the information is available on Wikipedia. However, I'd love to have the answer to "Why should I choose / not choose this distribution?", as this information is kind of hard to gather.

Comment: those questions tend to be subjective, no? as for wikipedia, we can link to wikipedia as well :)

Comment: you could start a community wiki, asking posters to list advantages and disadvantages of different distributions.... Think this would cover a few issues that are central to the **NIX** side of life.

Comment: oh I would love to open a wiki like that, but wouldn't it be a "subjective" question?